# Is it possible to mine a close asteroid without being noticed?

Tags: space, mining

Technology level, close future.

A scientist observing  [101955 Bennu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101955_Bennu) calculates the rotation it should have according to the [Yarkovsky–O'Keefe–Radzievskii–Paddack effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky%E2%80%93O%27Keefe%E2%80%93Radzievskii%E2%80%93Paddack_effect) and finds out that it does not match the actual rotation. He concludes that the asteroid has a density far higher than expected, there must be heavy elements at its centre.

The SharksWishfulThinking corporation decides they want to mine the asteroid. Their plan is to deploy some robots that will dig a tunnel towards the centre. The first layer should be easy, probably some rubble to remove, but then probably there is rock to be cut and that is not a good environment for cutting tools, therefore they decide to use cutting lasers powered by solar panels.

They submit the plan to their government, but it is eventually rejected. The risk that the digging will cause some splinters to break off, in a trajectory close to Earth, is too high. They try to submit their plans to other governments, they embellish their plan adding a rotating catapult that will hurl some debris into space casing micro-deviation of the asteroid trajectory farther from the Earth (like the mass drive principle). But their plans are still rejected.

They want to go on anyway, launching some fake missions to a farther object that change course at the last moment. But at this point they are under observation, can they get there unnoticed?

Comment: As written, this is a VTC:Too Story-Based question. They will if you want them to (and contrive the circumstances that permit it) or won't if you don't want them to (and contrive the circumstances that forbid it). To avoid question closure, (a) choose which path you want and (b) [edit] the question to reflect that choice (e.g., ask something like, "given the technology of today, would it be possible to detect the use of lasers powerful enough for hard-rock mining on an asteroid without directly observing the asteroid?").

Comment: BTW, the reason my example question avoids the future ("close future") is that every moment of the future creates possibilities that add to the Too Story-Based problem. In the "close future" I could have a near-field EM detection system (analogous to RADAR but more broadly applicable) that's used to detect spaceflight in the same way RADAR detects airplanes that could be flying anywhere. Given that story-based assumption, the answer becomes "no." Can you see my point about you having to make the story-based choices before asking questions?

Comment: This is possible, if all Intelligence agencies, hobby astronomers, space agencies and amateurs collectively decide to not look in Bennu´s vague direction or ask whatever happened to those fake missions. So it isnt possible.

Comment: Minus the fluff, your question appears to be "_can you fly a spacecraft to Bennu without anyone noticing?_", and not about mining at all. Stealth in space is tricky, to say the least, so you'll need to give some details about how long you're prepared to take flying there, and what tech-level everyone involved is. Maybe delete the irrelevant stuff, add the important details and see about getting your question reopened.,

Comment: @StarfishPrime I think it's worse than that. Energy usage during mining could be detected. Changes in the attitude and orbit of the asteroid (ignoring size, the bigger it is the less this is an issue) due to mining. The presence of a growing cloud of detrius due to mine tailings.... There's a lot that could be detected beyond the transit of ships. Although transit is a big one since you need to haul the goods somewhere and it's assumed it would happen more than once.

Comment: @FluidCode, I urge you to make the decision of how you want the story to proceed. I think a question asking *how the mining operation could be detected* (based on the presumption that the company proceeds with the project) would prove very fruitful. You will need to [edit] your post to express that change.

Comment: @JBH the question just ends with "_can they get there unnoticed?_" without actually worrying about mining. All the fluff got sidelined, but never actually got removed from the post.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Wow, I completely overlooked that! You're right, it appears the only question is whether or not they'd be noticed flying to the asteroid. I really wish the OP would help to clear this up. There could be several fun questions here.

Comment: My quick thought is: if they did not submit their queries to any governments those chances would be significantly higher to being not detected. :P I mean, in such era of such technologies all nearby asteroids would be already sorted by purpose by managers of extraterrestrial deposits. So, in my opinion, either they are inside that business, or they must work as implicit as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would not be party to space crimes, but to answer your purely hypothetical question (wink, wink)...

Take an inflatable dummy version of your craft. This must have some gyro stabilisation so it holds its position without rotating. Take a large, foldable mirror. Also buckets and spades for Bennu.

Get to high orbit. Wait until you are close to the sun as seen from Earth. Inflate the dummy craft. Put your craft behind the mirror. The mirror will reflect a random part of space. It will be warmer than space, so someone snooping in far IR might spot it. It will be visible on radar. But why would they be looking?

Off to Bennu, always keeping the mirror between you and Earth out to LEO in case someone happens to look in your direction. The tricky bit will be as you get to Bennu, because telescopes will probably be pointed in that direction. Try to get to Bennu when it is close to the Sun as seen from Earth.

Return is the reverse process: back to the dummy, deflate dummy and fold mirror, then back home for tea and cake.